# How to get WP editors tinyMCE instances

Tags: tinymce, wp-editor

My main goal is to get editor content when it changes and update a live preview. For this I need to add an event listener to the editor. BTW, I have two editor in the same page and the page is loaded via ajax.

Now back to my problem. I can't get to the instance of the tinyMCE editors. [I can `console.log()` them but get empty result when I try to stringify them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546953/cant-access-object-property-even-though-it-exists-returns-undefined).

Below is the result of `console.log(tinymce.editors)`.

[image: console.log(tinymce.editors)]

So, whenever I try to access editors using `tinymce.editors.contentleft`, `tinymce.editors['contentleft']`, `tinymce.get('contentleft')` or `tinymce.EditorManager.get('contentleft')` in all these cases I get `undefined` or `null`

Working more then couple days on this. Would appreciate a proper direction soon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you wait for the `SetupEditor` event then you can access the editors:

```
add_action( 'admin_print_footer_scripts', function () {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function ($) {
        if (typeof tinymce !== 'undefined') {
            tinymce.on('SetupEditor', function (editor) {
                if (editor.id === 'contentLeft') {
                    // Could use new 'input' event instead.
                    editor.on('change keyup paste', function (event) {
                        console.log('content=%s', this.getContent());
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
    </script>
    <?php
} );
```

Comment: spot on! So, I guess I was running the script early?

Comment: Yes! (tinymce takes several microseconds to setup each editor so the fact that yours is a secondary one probably exasperated the situation.)

Comment: ps: we should probably add a `typeof tinymce != 'undefined'` check, to avoid error on pages where *tinymce* isn't defined.

Comment: Good point @birgire ta, I'll update the answer...

Comment: I think `function(editor)` should be `function(event) { var editor = event.editor;` ..