# Keyboard shortcut for updating a page or post?

Tags: posts, pages, javascript, editor

What is the *keyboard shortcut* key for *updating* a page or post?  It could save me a lot of time as rolling down a page draft is time consuming.

Answer (score 10):

I was curious about this and checked the Codex on [keyboard shortcuts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Keyboard_Shortcuts), but didn't find it mentioned there.

I searched and found out that this seems to be already solved, e.g. [here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/save-with-keyboard/) and [here](https://github.com/johnbillion/wordpress-keyboard-shortcuts).

I haven't tested out these other plugins so I'm not sure how they solve it, but I decided to take on the challenge and see how this could be solved ;-)

So here's my hack for creating shortcuts for:

```
ctrl+s : Save Draft
ctrl+p : Publish / Update
```

with the following *test plugin* that runs within the [`after_wp_tiny_mce`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/112192/26350) hook:

```
/**
 * Plugin Name: Testing ctrl+s and ctrl+p for saving and publishing posts.
 * Plugin URI:  https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/199411/26350
 */
add_action( 'after_wp_tiny_mce', function()
{?><script>
    ( function ( $ ) {
        'use strict';
        $( window ).load( function () {
            wpse.init();
        });
        var wpse = {
            keydown : function (e) {
                if( e.ctrlKey && 83 === e.which ) {
                    // ctrl+s for "Save Draft"
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $( '#save-post' ).trigger( 'click' ); 
                } else if ( e.ctrlKey && 80 === e.which ) {
                    // ctrl+p for "Publish" or "Update"
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $( '#publish' ).trigger( 'click' );
                }
            },
            set_keydown_for_document : function() {
                $(document).on( 'keydown', wpse.keydown );
            },
            set_keydown_for_tinymce : function() {
               if( typeof tinymce == 'undefined' )
                   return;
               for (var i = 0; i < tinymce.editors.length; i++)
                   tinymce.editors[i].on( 'keydown', wpse.keydown );
           },
           init : function() {
               wpse.set_keydown_for_document();
               wpse.set_keydown_for_tinymce();
           }
       }                                                        
    } ( jQuery ) );
    </script><?php });
```

I added the *wpse.keydown* event-callback to every *tinymce* editor on the page, so the shortcuts would be available from there too.

Note that I use the `after_wp_tiny_mce` hook, as a convinient test-hook on a **vanilla** install, since we're dealing with the *tinymce* javascript object.
When we ship such a plugin, we should enqueue it from a .js file, as usual.

We could also use the `SetupEditor` event of *tinymce*, as mentioned [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/192931/26350) by @bonger, but here I've added an extra check to see if *tinymce* is defined, to avoid javascript error on pages where it's not defined:

```
// Keydown for tinymce
if( typeof tinymce != 'undefined' )
{
    tinymce.on( 'SetupEditor', function (editor) {
        wpse.set_keydown_for_tinymce();
    });
}
// Keydown for document
wpse.set_keydown_for_document();
```

We could probably setup native *tinymce* shortcuts as well.

This might need some testing & adjustments, but it seems to work on my install.

Comment: ps: just want to mention that if the page is loaded in *Text* mode and then switched back to the *Visual* mode, the tinymce keydown event will not fire.

Comment: What's the reasoning behind hooking this to tinymce and not to the post edit screen?

Comment: Good question. Since I'm dealing with the *tinymce* javascript object, then I thought `after_wp_tiny_mce` would be a handy test-hook for a vanilla install, where I don't expect `remove_post_type_support( 'post', 'editor' )` or multiple *tinymce* editors on a page.
But other hooks would work, but we have to make sure *tinymce* is defined. But we would ship our plugin by enqueue it from a .js file, in the usual way. @JanBeck

Comment: Thanks for the clarification about your intention to enqueue it as a .js file. I'm still wondering though, why you even care about tinymce at all. Even if your post edit screen only contains a title box wouldn't you still want to be able to save via keyboard shortcut? I guess the question is whether keyboard events happening inside the tinymce are bubbling up into the "outside" post edit screen. Have you tested that?

Comment: During my testing, I found out that if I skip the `wpse.set_keydown_for_tinymce()` part, then `wpse.set_keydown_for_document()` will not catch the *ctrl+{p,s}* keydown events from the *tinymce* editor. So that's why I bothered with the *tinymce* in the first place ;-) If that could be skipped, that would be great @JanBeck

Answer (score 1):

The question is old, but there is a plugin for this purpose:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/save-with-keyboard/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a shorter version of birgire's answer ( and uses no JQUERY ):

```
add_action( 'after_wp_tiny_mce', function() {
?>
    <script>
        addEventListener("keydown", () => {
            const updateButton = document.getElementsByClassName('editor-post-publish-button')[0]
            if (event.ctrlKey && event.key === 's') {
                event.preventDefault();
                updateButton.click();
            }
        })
    </script>
<?php
});
```

editor-post-publish-button is class for save/update button, if you want to trigger something else find it's class and enter it instead.